# SVD matrixes do not coincide with Eigen decomposition for covariance matrix

Tags: pca, python, multivariate-analysis, scikit-learn, svd

I am comparing the output from the singular value decomposition with the eigendecomposition of the covariance matrix (symmetric matrix). I am expecting that the Eigenvector and a non-diagonal matrix of SVD to be similar, yet they are not. I found that I need to flip and multip one column by -1. Pricnc[pe components could be calculated using either the eigendecomposition or SVD. Given that the eigendecomposition give different output from the SVD for the covariance matrix may yield different PCA output.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 

A=np.array([[1,3,2],
       [4,8,2],
       [3,9,7],
       [22,11,17],
       [55,33,66]])


A=A-np.mean(A,0)
print(np.dot(A.T,A)/(A.shape[0]-1))
co=np.cov(A.T)
print(co)
#%%
[D,UI]=np.linalg.eigh(co)
[aa,bb,cc]=np.linalg.svd(co)
print (UI)
print(aa)

UI
array([[-0.15348562, -0.77609875, -0.61164768],
   [-0.85628748,  0.41338399, -0.30965372],
   [ 0.49316722,  0.47621886, -0.72801215]])

aa
array([[-0.61164768,  0.77609875, -0.15348562],
   [-0.30965372, -0.41338399, -0.85628748],
   [-0.72801215, -0.47621886,  0.49316722]])

aa[:,::-1]
array([[-0.15348562,  0.77609875, -0.61164768],
   [-0.85628748, -0.41338399, -0.30965372],
   [ 0.49316722, -0.47621886, -0.72801215]])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the definition of an eigenvector $v$ and eigenvalue $\lambda$
$$
\begin{align}Av &=\lambda v \\
A(-v) &= \lambda (-v)
\end{align}$$
we can see that eigenvectors are only identified up to a nonzero multiple. Your discovery that multiplying by $-1$ makes the results coincide is not surprising, and amounts to a difference in how the two methods work.

Comment: thank, any idea how to explain mismatch in only part of the matrix (one column) and not the whole matrix. I added the values of the matrix that I get above. Thanks

Comment: @kernel One column is an eigenvector. My answer says that the sign and magnitude of an eigenvector is *arbitrary.*